# Last Record from Mysqli Database not showing

Tags: mysql, record

Thank you in advance for your help.

For some reason I cannot get the last record from the Database to show when I retrieve information from it.

This was working just fine until I upgraded from PHP 5 to PHP 7.1

```
    <?php
    $servername = "xxxxxxxx";
    $username = "xxxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxxx";
    $dbname = "xxxxxxxx";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

  //Second Half

  $sql="SELECT * FROM Online_Customers order by id DESC LIMIT 100";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch_assoc() removed in PHP 7

change

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

to

```
$row = $result->fetch_array()
```

Comment: Hi Xun and thank you for your help. I just tried what you wrote. It still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed. I removed the if statement and it's working just fine. If someone is having the same problem please let me know and I can guide you through.